# What does "Your mind is on fire but it's not enough" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, idioms

I know that the song is kind of poetic, but I fail to interpret this part. What do you think it means?

[009SoundSystem Born To Be Wasted](http://www.songlyrics.com/009-sound-system/born-to-be-wasted-lyrics/)

> Oh, the rock's not gonna stop, so let's rip it up
>
> The beats are gonna
>   drop, you can trip em' up
>
> **Your mind is on fire but it's not enough**
>
> We
>   were born to be wasted

Comment: "Your mind is on fire" = you are very excited, or you are very enthusiastic. But it's not enough (implying, you need to do more in order to enhance your experience, because you are "born to be wasted" anyway). But it's really offtopic, because such lyrics could be interpreted in a miriad ways.

Comment: One possible meaning of **wasted** = not put to good use, not allowed to realize one's potential.

Answer (score 2):

The short song is about being **on drugs**, **getting wasted**

The refrain

> We were born to be wasted

is reflected in the last two lines

> Ain't worth livin'
>   If you can't get your kicks

**kicks** = **have fun** and often means taking a recreational drug of choice

The song is referring to many things happening in the world and around the listener

**Mind on fire** means having one's mind in an **altered state of consciousness**, possibly **thinking too fast**, or having **too many thoughts at once**.  These states are usually **drug induced**

It may be an allusion to **Born To Be Wild** by Steppenwolf where there is a similar listing of things happening around the listener.

Comment: But in the original video clip of the song, it shows soldiers and military officers in the chaos of a war. Many people said that "Born to be wasted" refers to how soldiers and people are being wasted during a state of war. Part of the song is "This gun's blowin up it's just a warning shot. This plane's takin' off on a terror run. This night's gonna end like a missile drop"

Comment: It could also be a play on the different meanings of **wasted**. There is an alternative to the military video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zv3glNKPuEs)

Comment: hahaha lol. I wouldn't have imagined that. Yeah the lyrics are kind of weird. There are many verses of other songs by the same band that I don't understand completely.

Comment: **009 Sound System** really interesting history due to AudioSwap and being the National Anthem for YouTube(!). On the videos: interesting how same song, different pictures can be so different, eh? It's **electro-trance**, so understanding the words is less important to **feeling the beat** (whether or not one's **wasted**)